# Free/Opensource Tool for VS2010 in-IDE Unit Testing with C# Silverlight 4.0

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

We are currently looking for a Unit Testing tool that runs inside VS2010 for a C# Silverlight 4.0 project.

The first tool we tested (and was our preferred choice) was NUnit. But it's not compiled for Silverlight. We found a non-official build that was done for an older Silverlight version, but we would like to have a tool that works with Silverlight 4.0 out of the box.

We noticed the default MSTest tools dont run out of the box on Silverlight, but we did find the Silverlight Unit Testing framework. That runs "ok", but it pops up an external window (app) that does the unit testing. We are actually looking for an in-IDE solution, where the information comes in, for example, a tool window.

We did take a look at SilverUnit, but were unable to get that up and running. Plus that's not free/opensource.

Same goes for the AgUnit plugin for R#, we could only use that with an older version of R# not with the latest version, and again, that's not free/opensource (The plugin is, but R# is not).

Does anyone have any experience with C# Silverlight 4.0 unit testing inside the VS2010 IDE?

If all else fails we will be using the Silverlight Unit Testing framework, with the separate app popup, but would like to have it "really" in-IDE.

Thanks!

Huron.

Comment: I work with NUnit for Silverlight and Resharper (this tool isn't free, but in my case it is paid by the company). But I heard that Silverlight 5 will support Visual Studio unit tests, I hope it won't be long to wait.

Comment: We actually did not want to try the NUnit for Silverlight port, but will take a look at it, seems I got not much choice there. I guess the waiting is for SL5 then :)  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Silverlight application that we're talking about here is part of a larger solution which has a FrontEnd (Silverlight) and backend (Standard .NET).

Most of the decission making code and the heavy lifting is done in the backend. Which meant our Frontend was very light on code and needed very little testing.

For the rest of our testing needs, we ended up with using Resharper to run the tests while using the default MS-Test framework.

And since we moved to Silverlight 5, that's just a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can have support in IDE for Silverlight testing. You can look at [Silverlight Testing Automation Tool](http://statlight.codeplex.com/) - this tool can automate testing process for SL.

Comment: I have had a look at statlight, but cant get it to work properly. Still, thanks for your input!